# How do you determine how many results are in the current query batch?

Tags: soql, api, soap-api, query, java

We're using Java 8, v 33.0 of the SF API and trying to build an endpoint in Java to iterate over results.  I have this

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult;
...
        QueryResult queryResults = connection.query(query);
        System.out.println("size: " + queryResults.getSize());
        if (queryResults.getSize() > 0)
            {
                boolean done = false;
                while (!done)
                {
                    for (int j=0;j<queryResults.getSize();j++) {
                        // cast the SObject to a strongly-typed Account
                            final Account account = (Account)queryResults.getRecords()[j];
```

But I'm running into an issue.  The "queryResults.getSize()" returns a number over 9000.  However, while iterating the results, we eventually get teh error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2000
```

What's the correct way to determine how many results are in the current batch?

Comment: Have you tried just referencing `.size` as a property instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getSize() refers to the total size; check the size of the `records` member instead. This is demonstrated in the [WSC](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector) documentation:

```
if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
    for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
      // cast the SObject to a strongly-typed Contact
      Contact c = (Contact)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
      System.out.println("Id: " + c.getId() + " - Name: "+c.getFirstName()+" "+
          c.getLastName()+" - Account: "+c.getAccount().getName());
    }
  }
```

Realistically, your code needs to look something like this:

```
while(true) {
    processRecords(queryResults.getRecords());
    if(queryResults.isDone()) {
        break;
    }
    queryResults = queryMore(queryResults);
}
```